# Input type="checkbox" value=0 showing error (NULL)

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

[image: Toggles Image]

I have designed the checkbox like this, If checkbox is checked then the input `value` will be `1` else it'll be `0`

I have added logic with javascript

```
    <script>
        $('#exams, #materials, #notes, #course_live,, #schedule').on(
            'change',
            function() {
                this.value = this.checked ? '1' : '0';
            }).change();
    </script>
```

Now when I submit the form if the checkbox is checked it's working perfect, but if the checkbox is not checked it showing error:

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'exams' cannot be null`

But I want this that if the checkbox is not checked then the value should be 0, And it's showing perfectly in Inspect, I have removed the validation from laravel but showing the same. Please help me out.

Comment: Please share more details - how does the PHP code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 Ways :

1st: Conditional set in **PHP**

```
empty($request->input('your_input')) ? 0 : 1 ;
```

2nd: Set **Database** `default` to `0` (DB will convert null values to 0 automatically)

3rd: HTML trick: as **Marwelln** answer:  you can put a hidden input before your checkbox with a default value.

```
<input type='hidden' name='foobar' value='0' /> <!-- default value if foobar checkbox is not checked -->
```

Comment: Thank you, I have choosed the first method

Answer (score 1):

When an html input type with `checkbox` is not checked it will not exist in the post array. To solve this you can put a hidden input before you checkbox with a default value.

```
<input type='hidden' name='foobar' value='0' /> <!-- default value if foobar checkbox is not checked -->
<input type='checkbox' name='foobar' value='1' />
```

If you use this method you can remove your javascript `change` trigger as it's not needed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Can I do this something like in laravel validation that if the value is null then it'll become 0?

Comment: I don't know how you have it set up but if you're using a model then you should be able to type cast it to a boolean. `protected $casts = ['field' => 'boolean']`.  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: $name = $request->input('name', 'default value');

Answer (score 1):

Best practice to follow is to check if your checkboz is present in request or not
Using

`$request->has('key')`

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbox isn't checked, then it won't be a successful control, and its value will not be included in the submitted data. Giving it a different value when it isn't checked is pointless.

Handle this server-side instead. For example:

```
<form method="post">
<input name="toggle[]" value="exams" type="checkbox">
<input name="toggle[]" value="materials" type="checkbox">
<input name="toggle[]" value="notes" type="checkbox">
<input name="toggle[]" value="course_live" type="checkbox">
<input name="toggle[]" value="schedule" type="checkbox">
<button>Submit</button>
</form>

<?php

$toggle = [
    "exams" => 0,
    "materials" => 0,
    "notes" => 0,
    "course_live" => 0,
    "schedule" => 0,
];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    foreach ($toggle as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($key, $_POST['toggle'])) {
            $toggle[$key] = 1;
        }
    }

    ?><pre><?php
        echo json_encode($toggle,  JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    ?></pre><?php
}
```